# Origin of tee's name

Tags: history, tee

Does anybody know where the `tee` command-line utility got it's name, I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: [The command is named after the T-splitter used in plumbing...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))

Comment: @don_crissti, you should post an answer!

Comment: @gmarmstrong - no, I don't think this deserves an answer, really...

Answer (score 10):

`tee` (pronounced like the letter T) takes its name from the **T**-splitter used in plumbing, and which allows the flow of liquid to go to two directions at once. This is appropriate since `tee` allows redirecting the output to stdout and to a file at the same time.

[Image from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))

[image]

In this example, the output of `ls -l` is piped to `tee` which redirects it both to the file `file.txt` and to the pager `less`.

Comment: Once one knows about the "garden hose" metaphor, the names of commands such as `tee` and [`y`](https://jpsoft.com/help/y.htm) become fairly self-evident.

Comment: @JdeBP,  that `y` looks like `cat -`. I suppose, as a Unix utility, we would have to call it `why` by analogy with `t`/`tee` and because it's not clear why it's needed. Let's not try to look too hard for a real-world analogy for `pee` (pipe tee).